# Зависание Hover

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема: при наведении на картинку она должна плавно округляться, но вместо этого при наведении проходит пол секунды и она округляется сразу. В чем ошибка?

```html
<body>
    <header class="topMenu">
        <div class="menu">
            <img src="image/img1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <img src="image/img2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <img src="image/img3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
   </header>
</body>
```

```css
.menu{
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;

}
.menu img:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.01);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.01);
    transform: scale(1.01);
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.menu img {
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте, пожалуйста, ещё раз отображение. На сколько я вижу, картинки округляются плавно, как написано у Вас в необходимом поведении элементов.

Comment: Chrome, Moz, Edge, Yandex все корректно отображает.
На твоей стороне какие-то проблемы. Ctrl + f5 или Сtrl + R в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к стилю **.menu img** `border: 1px solid transparent;` и все у вас заработает. Скорее всего у Вас Firefox так отрисовывал анимация. В общем, добавив прозрачный бордер, он (бордер) в дальнейшем будет анимироваться как Вы хотели во всех браузерах поддерживающих анимацию.

```
.menu img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```